# Merchello Notification throwing this error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, smtp, umbraco, windows-server-2016

I've been getting this exception when Merchello tries to send an email notification:

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I am using send grid and I've tried the exact same credentials that I was using on Local and it works fine locally.

I'm sure it's something to do with the server, what I've tried so far:

- Made sure SMTP service is running on the server
- Opened the port 587 in the firewall
- Temporally disabled the firewall
- Tried a different SMTP provider
- Added this to the web config:

  ```
   <system.net>
     <defaultProxy> 
       <proxy usesystemdefault="False"/> 
     </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>
  ```

More form the stack trace:

```
 System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> 
 System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the 
 target machine actively refused it
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the port to 25 and it worked, not sure why I was asked to use 587.

Answer (score 0):

The same port might be configured for some other in your IIS bindings

you can also check by the following command in ADMIN mode of your command prompt

C:>netstat -anb

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I checked and nothing was using 587 I had a look in the services file too. I got it working by changing the port to 25, not sure why I was asked to use 587 over 25 as it's not blocked or anything. Thanks